# Algorithm for quad (2 tris) indices

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

I have a list of random amounts of vertices that I want to get indices of 2 triangles in the shape of a quad. Every four vertices should make the 2 triangles. e.g:

```
0,1,2,  0,2,3,
4,5,6,  4,6,7,
8,9,10, 8,10,11
```

I'm sure this is quite simple but can't figure out how to generate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
For quad : int from 0 To VertexCount / 4
    //First triangle
    index[6 * quad + 0] = 4 * quad
    index[6 * quad + 1] = 4 * quad + 1
    index[6 * quad + 2] = 4 * quad + 2

    //Second triangle
    index[6 * quad + 3] = 4 * quad;
    index[6 * quad + 4] = 4 * quad + 2
    index[6 * quad + 5] = 4 * quad + 3
Next
```